# What is going wrong with fread() in my code?

Tags: c, cs50, fread

Here is an excerpt of the code I'm trying now in relation to my previous problems in cs50 'Recover'.

I've tried everything with `fread`, but for some reason it simply isn't working the way I want it to.

In this loop, I'm trying to figure out how `fread` actually works.

My question with `fread` is - does it read 512 bytes of data 1 at a time from file pointed to (`rawdata`) each time it's called? In that case, my code should work since the loop is running indefinitely, calling the function over and over and hence moving the stream position/file cursor (I don't know what its called) 512 bytes at a time. I have a break from the loop with `feof(rawdata)`.

I'm using this small program to aid me with Recover from cs50 pset4.

```
    // In a loop, until the end of file has been reached,
    while (true) {
        // Zeroing counter
        jpg_counter = 0;
        // Reading 512 bytes into the array of bytes
        fread(bytes, 512, 1, rawdata);
        
        // Searching the 512 bytes for JPEG signatures - bytes[3] with bitwise AND
        if (bytes[0] == 0xff && bytes[1] == 0xd8 && bytes[2] == 0xff && (bytes[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
            jpg_counter++;
        }
        
        // If found JPG, add total and keep going till end of file
        if (jpg_counter != 0) {
            total++;
        }
 
        //feof returns a non zero value only at the end of a file
        if (feof(rawdata) != 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", total);
```

Comment: Please note, 'bytes' is my previously declared array of bytes of size 512

Comment: you should call `fread(bytes, 1, 512, rawdata)` and check the returned value, see document of this function here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: Hi, I've tried this. For some reason, I got a big fat 0 returned by fread for both fread(bytes, 1, 512, rawdata) and fread(bytes, 512, 1, rawdata), even though perror(rawdata) returned success and it definitely isn't the end of file.

Comment: @thefailagent is your file big enough?

Comment: Yes the file is much bigger (exact size unknown)

Comment: You're only checking for the JPEG signature if it starts at an offset divisible by 512. I assume you need to find it at any offset, including the middle of the buffer, or even spanning two different 512-byte buffers.

Comment: @thefailagent You can't do `perror(rawdata)`. Is it `ferror(rawdata)` you're looking for?

Comment: Oh I didnt know that existed. I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 major problems with your approach:

- you do not correctly test for end of file in the reading loop. You should use the return value of `fread` to determine if you have read at least one byte from the stream, and you should pass the arguments in the opposite order: you are reading as many as 512 bytes:

  ```
    size_t n;
    while ((n = fread(bytes, 1, 512, rawdata)) > 0) {
        // n bytes were read from the file.
  ```
- you only test the first 4 bytes for a JPEG signature. Unless the file is known to have a very specific structure, you probably want to search the block for signatures.
- care must be taken to handle signatures overlapping blocks, ie: that start at the end of a 512 byte block but end on the next block.

Here is a modified version:

```c
int count_jpeg(FILE *rawdata) {
    unsigned char bytes[3 + 512];
    int pos = 0, end, i;
    int total = 0;
    size_t nread;
    // In a loop, until the end of file has been reached,
    while ((nread = fread(bytes + pos, 1, 512, rawdata)) > 0) {
        end = pos + nread - 3;
        for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            // Searching the block for JPEG signatures - bytes[3] with bitwise AND
            if (bytes[i] == 0xff && bytes[i + 1] == 0xd8
            &&  bytes[i + 2] == 0xff && (bytes[i + 3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
                total++;
                i += 3;
            }
        }
        // copy the last 3 bytes to the beginning of the block
        for (i = pos = 0; i < 3; i++)
            if (end + i >= 0) {
                bytes[pos++] = bytes[end + i];
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", total);
    return total;
}
```

**EDIT:** if the JPEG signatures are known to be aligned on 512-byte boundaries, the scanning loop can be removed, but reading a partial block at the end of the file should still be possible:

```c
int count_jpeg(FILE *rawdata) {
    unsigned char bytes[512];
    int total = 0;

    // In a loop, until the end of file has been reached,
    while (fread(bytes + pos, 1, 512, rawdata) > 4) {
        /* check for a signature at the beginning of the block */
        if (bytes[0] == 0xff && bytes[1] == 0xd8
        &&  bytes[2] == 0xff && (bytes[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", total);
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I have used the first four bytes because the problem set in question explicitly stated that the JPEG signatures would be block aligned always to the start of a 512 byte block followed by slack space, if any. But I guess, it is better practice to search through the entire block anyway. I will try implement this loop and see what I can understand from it. Thanks again!

Comment: @thefailagent: I was not aware of this restriction that greatly simplifies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

man page of fread states

> The function fread() reads nmemb items of data, each size bytes long,
> from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at the location
> given by ptr

so you can store number of elements read in a variable and check if 512 bytes are read.

```
int nmenb = fread(bytes, 512, 1, rawdata);

if( nmemb != 1 )
{
  //exit
}
else{
      // 512 bytes read successfully 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to implement this